# FFmpeg concat with watermarks and audio "stream specifier in filtergraph description matches no streams."

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate an arbitrary number of videos with a series of watermarks over them:

`ffmpeg -i segment0.mp4 -i segment1.mp4 -i ... segmentn.mp4 -i end.mp4 -i ../../watermark/watermark1280/watermark_%05d.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]...[n:v]concat=n=n:v=1:a=0 [v], [v] overlay [p]" -map "[v]" -an -y output.mp4`

I am getting the following error:

`Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v]...[n:v]concat=n=n:v=1:a=0 [v], [v] overlay [p] matches no streams.`

Here is the full output of my latest attempt:

`ffmpeg version N-78734-g666e2ed Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 25.101 / 57. 25.101
  libavformat    57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 36.100 /  6. 36.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'segment0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.01, start: 0.010000, bitrate: 6 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'segment1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.99, start: 0.066000, bitrate: 5014 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 5008 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'segment2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.01, start: 0.009000, bitrate: 424 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1111 kb/s, 59 fps, 59 tbr, 15104 tbn, 118 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'segment3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.85, start: 0.205000, bitrate: 5058 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 5050 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'segment4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.77, start: 0.282000, bitrate: 5174 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 5167 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'segment5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.01, start: 0.006000, bitrate: 955 kb/s
    Stream #5:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1448 kb/s, 59 fps, 59 tbr, 15104 tbn, 118 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #5:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../../slate/Void_test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3176 kb/s
    Stream #6:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 3169 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 11988 tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #7, image2, from '../../watermark/watermark1280/watermark_%05d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:14.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #7:0: Video: png, ya8(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v][4:v][5:v][6:v]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0 [v], [v] overlay [p] matches no streams.`

Also, if someone can help me do this with a single mp3 audio input over the whole concatenated video, that'd be helpful, too.

Comment: segment0 has no video stream,but you have referenced it in the concat.

Comment: @Mulvya Indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, if someone can help me do this with a single mp3 audio input
>   over the whole concatenated video, that'd be helpful, too.

If you will input your mp3 as n+1 input, you should add `-map n+1:a` at the end.

And actually you write `-map "[v]"` is that you really want to get or you need to write `-map [p]`?